# Changing from form to link

Tags: php, html

I have the following form with a drop-down. This selects a language choice.

Now I want to change this drop-down to a link with flag images. How can I get the same effect by using image links.

```
<form action="http://localhost/myapp/index.php/welcome/index" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8">
 <select name="lang">
  <option value="">Select Language</option>
  <option value="english">English</option>
  <option value="japanese">Japanese</option>
 </select>
 <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Change Language"  />
</form>
```

Comment: Do you mean inserting image inside `select`?

Comment: you can add background image to the <option> tag

Comment: You can check this link
http://binnyva.blogspot.in/2006/01/icons-for-select-menu-options-in.html

Answer (score 0):

try this:
replace `<select>` with this:

```
<ul>
   <li><a href="address1"><img src="img/1/1.png"></a></li>
   <li><a href="address2"><img src="img/1/2.png"></a></li>
</ul>
```

and the css:

```
li{
  text-decoration:none;
  display:inline;
 }
```